# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'xx' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using the code below in my JSP

```
 <form:select path="defaultEmployee" id="defaultRestaurantEmployee" cssClass="select">

 </form:select>
```

And I have following object in my Form

```
private String defaultEmployee;
```

But I am getting above mentioned error. Any idea what can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your controller method which forwards to your jsp has

   model.addAttribute("Formbeanname", formObject);     ?
2. The jsp has similar structure ?

   `<`form:form modelAttribute="Formbeanname" method="POST" action="post">
            .........
           `<`form:select path="defaultEmployee" id="ABC">
               ................
              `<`/form:select>
   `<`/form:form>
3. `defaultEmployee` is property of formObject?

That all you need .